# Sort vector of vector using variable index

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm having some problems using the std sort function. I want to sort a vector of vector without using always the same index. I know I can use something like:

```
sort(dataset.begin(), dataset.end(), myfunction);
// or
std::sort(dataset.begin(), dataset.end(),
    [](const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b) {
        return a[2] < b[2]);
    });
```

In the first case I don't know how to include the specified index as an input of `myfunction`. 
In the second case, I though of including the index as an input of the function signature but I can't even make it compile as shown above!

The error:

> main.cpp:28:39: error: expected expression sort(dataset.begin(), dataset.end(), [](const vector& a, const vector& b)

Comment: Is it always the same index for one run? Or do you intend to compare for example element 1 of vector 0 with element 20 of vector 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **lambda function** - you can capture the `index` variable:

   ```
   std::size_t index = 2;
   std::sort(dataset.begin(), dataset.end(),
       [index](const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b) {
           return a[index] < b[index]);
       });
   ```
2. **function** - if you have

   ```
   bool myfunction(const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b, std::size_t index)
   ```

   you can [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) index to the third parameter:

   ```
   using namespace std::placeholders;
   std::size_t index = 2;
   std::sort(dataset.begin(), dataset.end(), std::bind(myfunction, _1, _2, index));
   ```

   Consider this solution inferior to lambdas, use it only when they're not available, or you'll be treated badly.

Comment: Don't use `int` ... use `std::size_t`.

Comment: I feel compelled to downvote you for mentioning that `bind` crap. It's superfluous and inferior to lambdas in the vast majority of cases, including this one.

Comment: Well, OP asked about that. He/she can also choose between the two.

Comment: He didn't ask about that, he just had a generic need to capture or bind a variable. There's nothing `std::bind` specific in it.

Answer (score 1):

You could capture `index` and use it within the lambda function:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> dataset = ...

std::size_t index = 2;
std::sort(dataset.begin(), dataset.end(),
    [index](const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b) {
    return a[index] < b[index];
});
```